# Invoking dos command form Perl doesn’t work properly after installing Chef

Tags: perl, chef-infra, perl-core

After installing Chef on windows, I found some dos commands no longer work in Perl if they contain forward slashes. For example, running `` `dir /AD .` `` in Perl will now give you some warning like `dir: /AD: No such file or directory` . I know the forward slash points to the root of the current working directory of the chef-client process. But it is really annoying this affects Perl as well. Is there any way to fix this?   Thanks.

More info to clarify the issue:
I am using a fairly clean win7 64bit machine with ActivePerl 5.8.8 and Chef client 11.12.2-1. The issue is clearly related to the Chef installation. First, it is on and off when I install and uninstall the Chef client. Second, when I run `dir /`, it lists contents of C:\opscode\chef\embedded folder.

Comment: `dir` is a DOS builtin, not a true command. Maybe try `cmd /C dir /AD .`?

Comment: That works. But I really want to know how come the chef installation can affect running dos built-in within Perl. Invoking the dos built-in directly used to work without any issue in our system.

Answer (score 3):

`Chef` isn't causing any problems.  My system responds the same to the command: `` my @dirs = `dir /AD .` ``.  It treats `/AD` as a directory instead of a flag throwing the same error message `"dir: /AD: No such file or directory"` before returning *all* of the files in the current directory.

Using mob's comment solution of `` my @dirs = `cmd /C dir /AD .` `` fixes the issue and returns the list of directories as desired.

However, the best method to solve this issue is just to make your perl code cross-platform compatible by not relying on OS specific builtins.  For example, getting the list of directories in the cwd is easily done using the following:

```
my @dirs = grep -d, <*>;
```

**Update**

I'm running Strawberry perl 5.18.2 on Windows 7 x64

```
C:\>perl -v

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
```

Given what you've shared about the scope of the task, I think that mob's solution is probably your best bet.  Yes, it'd be a pain to have to replace all of those backtick ``` `` ``` and `qx()` calls, but I don't foresee a better option.  Good luck figuring out if/how Chef is causing the issue.   Don't have anything else to add for now.

Comment: Thanks for trying this out and the suggestion. I just added more information in my post. The dos built-in used to work without any issue until I installed Chef. I agree the best practice to avoid OS specific built-ins. But I am working on a fairly large legacy project used internally and those built-ins are just everywhere. I am not going to argue it is good or bad for now. I want to understand the impact of Chef client installation first. What version of Perl do you use?

Comment: Amended my answer to include my system specs.